How large can a network of underground tunnels be before it collapses on itself?
How large can a network of underground tunnels be before it collapses on itself?
In my world I have an alien planet where most intelligent life lives underground in a global network of tunnels. These tunnels are dug by worms (big sci-fi worms) which live far below the "normal depth" of most inhabitants. This particular species of giant worm survives off thermosynthesis and lives in magma chambers, periodically rising to the relatively cooler temperatures of the upper crust and using the heat gradient to produce its energy before descending back into the lower crust. The worms are massive, and live on geological time scales, building up massive reserves of energy to then bore through rock and fuse the stone around them. The worms don't always make new tunnels, sometimes younger worms will simply use a previously carved tunnel whenever they need to surface for cooler temps, but over the years they have created a layer of tunnels 6-8km deep in which most of the species of my planet live, including intelligent ant-like creatures adapted to the high temperature of the tunnels.
Gravity is earthlike, despite the planet being four times the size of earth (It is significantly less dense.)
My question is specifically about big the worm tunnel network can actually be before it destabilizes the crust and just collapses in on itself. I imagine if it gets big enough, the weight of the stone above it would crush it and destroy everything, and while I definitely want cave-ins as natural disasters, I would like the wider tunnel network to be a relatively permanent fixture of the planet, stable enough for millions of years of evolution to happen.

Depends on what you call a tunnel and what technology the worms use to reinforce the tunnels. Realistic tunnels, say the size of railway or subway tunnels, need reinforcement to avoid collapsing. If you try to simply dig out the rocks and do not reinforce the tunnel it will collapse instantly.

A subway tunnel is an excellent analogy for what I am thinking of. As for how  the worms make it and whether or not it's reinforced, I was primarily thinking of them grinding through the stone and melting it as they pass, maybe adding a few secretions if it helps reinforce the walls.

Stack Exchange expects querents to research their questions before asking them (see [ask]). What has your research produced? Did you investigate underground cities or look into how much open space can be found in coal and salt mines? How about prairie dog towns?

Not enough for an answer, so as comment: what might help you is if the worms excrete metals to stabilize their tunnel walls - it would be an evolutionary advantage to leave behind stable tunnels, since the children of worms that do will have to expend less energy to rise and descend than those of worms whose tunnels collapse (so the children have to dig their own). This could also lead to evolutionary pressure benefitting worms that develop instincts to dig their tunnels where they don't collapse existing ones (because that might cause a chain reaction collapsing their own tunnel too)

On Earth, a subspecies of Homo Sapiens does dig tunnels for a living, deep underground. They're called miners and you can learn much from them.

One pervasive fact is, if you dig anywhere below the water table, it will soon fill with water: this is just gravity at work. An other is, on the geological timescale, the underground is fluid. Depending on the kind of rock you dig into, it may be fluid on a human timescale as well. In coal mines, tunnels must be dug again as soon as they are finished because they shrink to half their initial diameter in a few dozens of weeks (it's shale). In uranium mines, tunnels don't shrink at all (it's granite).

Tunnels in the deep crust won't hold up for long regardless of size.  A comment I recall seeing relative to the Kola Superdeep Borehole project (translated from Russian, I think, and I've long since lost the source) was that rocks as little as 5 km deep were as soft as putty.  The combination of pressure (gigapascals) and heat (above 1000C) meant that the borehole started to close even as they were drilling, forcing them to abandon the project at around 12 km depth when the drill became stuck.
It's worth remembering that deep crust (and moreso mantle) rocks, despite being technically solid, flow like a viscous liquid.  Over the time frame your worms live, their tunnels (to them) wouldn't be any more permanent than those an earthworm makes in soft soil, i.e. one good rain and they're gone.
Human mining operations have issues with rocks literally exploding out of the shaft or gallery walls due to the pressure of overburden, even when less than a kilometer deep, and South African gold mines go deep enough that humans can't survive in the mine for longer than a single shift due to the heat (air temperatures as high as 140F, as I recall).
Overall, then, I wouldn't expect any but the shallowest of the worm tunnels to have a useful lifetime combined with livable conditions, at least for anything that could live on the surface of Earth.
Concerning what percentage of the rock could be tunnels -- well, that's tricky.  Given your worms are using thermal boring (i.e. melting the rock into a denser form to make a space without having to remove tailings), in rock cool enough not to make flow an issue these (at least partially) self-shoring tunnels might locally make up 20% of the volume (this is about the limit in most hard rock mining).  Over a larger (continental) scale, I wouldn't expect more than 10% of a given craton to be open tunnel volume.
It's physically possible to arrange tunnels to give much higher porosity -- but unless it's done intentionally, it seems unlikely that your super-worms, just tunneling for their own purposes, would manage that.

The lower density of the planet will help somewhat. At 4x the size of earth but with equivalent surface gravity, the planet is 1/4 as dense as earth, making pressure at some depth 75% lower than on earth. The OP's 6-8km is still too deep to be feasible, but we might be able to go deeper than 1km.

@NuclearHoagie: Do you know many rocks four times less dense than granite? The relative density of granite is about 2.7. A rock one fourth as dense would be less dense than water and ice!

I'm actually not expecting earth creatures to survive in the tunnels. The "tunnel dwellers" are ant-like creatures and evolved to have an internal body temperature of 115 degrees Celsius, so I figure they'll be fine at the 6km depth I wanted to use. You do bring up an interesting point when you mention the shallowest tunnels might be useful, since the worms themselves are only important for how the tunnels got there, I'm more than open to the possibility of tunnels below a certain threshold being considered unstable, I just want to know how much tunnel space I could actually get away with.

@Doguskang - to reiterate Zeiss's point, it's not that they're unstable below a particular depth, it's that "tunnels" are meaningless, as the rock at those depths is more of an ooze than a solid.  It would be like boring tunnels through pudding.

Kola Superdeep Borehole has a wiki. The Russian wiki does mention a layer of "putty" at 7000m deep, but above and below that were granite layers (of different geological types, and likely micro-structure); this might have been a local abnormality. However, even granites do tend to flow under extreme pressure, I've read that scientists, based on that very borehole, declared that 12 km is the depth where they cave in under pressure alone.

@AlexP maybe the planet has no (or a much smaller) iron/nickel core somehow - replacing dense metal with less-dense molten rocks might help? And then the crust is less dense because it's swiss cheese (with a higher than usual gas content due to tunnels) too... Add some handwaving as needed?
